# flywaydb with multi branch git/jenkins pipeline

Tags: flyway

At this moment we develop a project that uses flyway DB. In the project we use a GIT multibranch Jenkins pipeline where upon every check in the application code is compliled and deployed on the test enviroment and in this deployment time the Flyway script is executed. The problem is that every branch might contain a different version of the flyway scripts which means that upon deployment it can happen that flyway throws a checksum error. The only solution we have thought about is to drop the Schema’s tables as an extension of the beforeValidation callback. The only problem with this approach is that the database recyclebin gets full very fast and it is not possible to expand the bin or deativate it.

The question is whether someone has a best idea of how to deal of how to work with flyway when developing on multiple branches possibly better than dropping the tables

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your application uses a single schema on the database. Would it be possible to create and use branch specific schema on the database and use these branch specific schema for flyway - database migration and deploying the app on top of these branch specific schema and testing this in jenkins pipeline?